# generate blank aidl file

Tags: android

This may sound stupid but for some reason I can't find anywhere on Eclipse that lets me generate blank .aidl files... Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a copy form this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html

and than use something liek th ecode2code eclips eplugin to generate code from the template you have created..

Answer (score 0):

There is no option (yet, I guess) to create a aidl file. You should just create a file (right click on the package -> new file ) and give it name with .aidl extension. Then in this file you should just add several lines:

1. The name of the package, for instance `package com.test;`
2. And just declare `interface IYourName {   }`

So as you can do only several things with android interface, there is no need to make a separate template for this.